# Percentage of total counts by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I'm trying to create an output that calculates the percentage of counts, out of total counts (in a data frame), by factor level, but can't seem to figure out how to retain the grouping structure in the output.

I can get the total counts that I want to divide by...

```
df %>% summarise(sum(num))
# 15
```

...and the total by group...

```
df %>% group_by(species) %>% summarise(sum(num))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#   species                  `sum(num)`
#   <chr>                         <int>
# 1 Farfantepenaeus duorarum          4
# 2 Farfantepenaeus notialis          0
# 3 Farfantepenaeus spp              11
```

But I can't get it to get it to look like this...

```
# ???
#   species                     Percent
#   <chr>                         <int>
# 1 Farfantepenaeus duorarum       4 / 15 = 0.267
# 2 Farfantepenaeus notialis       0 / 15 = 0.000
# 3 Farfantepenaeus spp           11 / 15 = 0.733
```

The closest I got was this, but because I used reframe() it returns the ungrouped data

```
df %>% group_by(species) %>% 
  summarise(factor_count=sum(num)) %>% 
  # ungroup() %>% 
  # Wanring: # Please use `reframe()` instead., When switching from `summarise()` 
  # to `reframe()`, remember that `reframe()` always returns an ungrouped data
  reframe(percent=factor_count/sum(df$num))

# A tibble: 3 × 1
  percent
    <dbl>
1   0.267
2   0    
3   0.733
```

Data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(species = c("Farfantepenaeus notialis", "Farfantepenaeus spp", 
"Farfantepenaeus notialis", "Farfantepenaeus notialis", "Farfantepenaeus duorarum", 
"Farfantepenaeus duorarum", "Farfantepenaeus notialis", "Farfantepenaeus spp", 
"Farfantepenaeus duorarum", "Farfantepenaeus spp", "Farfantepenaeus notialis", 
"Farfantepenaeus duorarum", "Farfantepenaeus spp", "Farfantepenaeus notialis", 
"Farfantepenaeus notialis", "Farfantepenaeus spp", "Farfantepenaeus duorarum", 
"Farfantepenaeus spp", "Farfantepenaeus spp", "Farfantepenaeus duorarum", 
"Farfantepenaeus duorarum", "Farfantepenaeus spp", "Farfantepenaeus spp", 
"Farfantepenaeus spp", "Farfantepenaeus notialis"), num = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L)), row.names = c(159897L, 174698L, 
236857L, 190237L, 327321L, 272931L, 304567L, 75538L, 109206L, 
351373L, 280332L, 163966L, 282183L, 341197L, 316962L, 354703L, 
343971L, 95333L, 244258L, 254061L, 87561L, 186908L, 221318L, 
258688L, 97737L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two steps: summarize group-totals, then percent-calcs on everything combined.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  summarize(Percent = sum(num), .by = species) %>%
  mutate(Percent = Percent / sum(Percent))
#                    species   Percent
# 1 Farfantepenaeus notialis 0.0000000
# 2      Farfantepenaeus spp 0.7333333
# 3 Farfantepenaeus duorarum 0.2666667
```

For your code:

- `reframe` is not necessary (mostly when the number of rows *changes*, it can often be used in place of `summarise`, but I haven't verified if/where the two differ significantly), and in fact here it will drop the `species` column
- (Almost) *Never* use `df$` in a pipe that starts with `df`: using `df$num` ignores anything you've done since the start of the pipe, meaning that grouping, filtering, additions/changes, etc, are not available in that version of `df`. There are certainly times when it is useful and even necessary, but they are few and far-between.

Answer (score 7):

Using `xtabs`.

```
> xtabs(num ~ species, df) |> proportions() |> as.data.frame()
                   species         Freq
1 Farfantepenaeus duorarum 0.2666666667
2 Farfantepenaeus notialis 0.0000000000
3      Farfantepenaeus spp 0.7333333333
```

Answer (score 6):

pass the value to `wt` parameter of the `count` function

```
df %>%
    count(species, wt = num/sum(.$num), name = 'percent')

                   species   percent
1 Farfantepenaeus duorarum 0.2666667
2 Farfantepenaeus notialis 0.0000000
3      Farfantepenaeus spp 0.7333333
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are two alternative approaches:

#### with `map_vec`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summarise(sum_num = sum(num), .by=species) %>% 
  mutate(percent = map_vec(sum_num, ~ .x /  sum(df$num)))
```

#### base R:

```
# credits to @r2evans: 
aggregate(num ~ species, data = df, sum) |>
  transform(percent = num/sum(num))

# or:
df_sums <- aggregate(num ~ species, data = df, sum)
df_sums$percent <- df_sums$num / sum(df$num)

df_sums
```

```
      species sum_num   percent
1 Farfantepenaeus notialis       0 0.0000000
2      Farfantepenaeus spp      11 0.7333333
3 Farfantepenaeus duorarum       4 0.2666667
```

Comment: I like base R :-) ... you can one-step it with `aggregate(..) |> transform(percent = num/sum(num))` (just because).

Comment: Thanks for sharing `transform()` I didn't have that readily available in memory.

Comment: It's one of those base-R functions that has been there for decades (literally, [41c2f73](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/41c2f7338c45dbf9eac99c210206bc3657bca98a)) but too often overlooked in my mind. One of the biggest differences from `mutate` (other than the recent `.by=` and other dot-args) is that `mutate` allows one to reference columns added/changed in the same call, whereas `transform` does not.